# postgres two version but psql always point to one

Tags: postgresql

I am having difficulties to understand how to upgrade from postgres 13 to 15 but I don't understand the process

What I did so far is I install postgres 15 so I have two version running on windows (13 -> port 5432 and 15-> port 5433)
I have pg_dump my database for backup

what I am trying to do now is to create the new database on postgres15

I have removed the PATH directory pointed to postgres 13. I have nothing now

But I dont understand my following actions below:
I go into the bin directory for postgres15 and I type psql -V I have postgres15 version
However when i try to createdb namedatabase it always point to postgres13 for some reasons

Please help to upgrade my knowledge

[image]

[image]

Comment: 5432 is the default port.  If you don't specify a port, that is what libpq-based binaries try to connect to.  If you want to connect to 5433, you have to specify it with `-p 5433`.  Both psql and createdb support this option.

Comment: thank you very much for your input. I was doing two mistakes, the one you mentioned but also I had to add the user postgres with the command -U postgres. It looks much better now thanks.